# How to instantiate Multiple Redis Connections for Publish Subscribe (node.js + node_redis)

Tags: node.js, redis, publish-subscribe, hapi.js, node-redis

### Scenario

Using **node_redis** to build a simple Redis Pubish Subscribe (chat) example: https://github.com/nelsonic/hapi-socketio-redis-chat-example (*with Hapi.js and Socket.io*)

We have created a node module **redis_connection.js** in our project ( see: http://git.io/vqaos ) to instantiate the Redis connection because we don't want to be *repeating* the code which connects (to RedisCloud) multiple times:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var url   = require('url');
var redisURL    = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL);
var redisClient = redis.createClient(redisURL.port, redisURL.hostname,
                  {no_ready_check: true});
redisClient.auth(redisURL.auth.split(":")[1]);

module.exports = redisClient;
```

Which we then *use* like this:

```
var redisClient = require('./redis_connection.js');

// Confirm we are able to connect to  RedisCloud:
redisClient.set('redis', 'working', redisClient.print);
redisClient.get('redis', function (err, reply) {
  console.log('RedisCLOUD is ' +reply.toString());
});
```

This works fine for normal GET/SET operations with Redis,
but when we try to instantiate multiple connections to Redis (e.g: one to publish, another to subscribe and a third just to GET/SET keys/values) we get an error:

### Issue

We are seeing the following error:

`Error: Connection in subscriber mode, only subscriber commands may be used`

What are we doing wrong?

Full code at the point where we see this issue: http://git.io/vqa6y

#### Note

We *tried* to dig through existing SO Q/A on this, e.g:

- [Publish subscribe with nodejs and redis(node_redis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140398/publish-subscribe-with-nodejs-and-redisnode-redis)
- [Redis publish/subscribe: see what channels are currently subscribed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952837/redis-publish-subscribe-see-what-channels-are-currently-subscribed-to)
- [how to use the redis publish/subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453463/how-to-use-the-redis-publish-subscribe)

but did not find a solution that *exactly* matched our situation...

(*any suggestions/help much appreciated!*)

Comment: Did any of the suggested solutions worked out for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## redis-connection node.js module

In the interest of keeping this *re-useable* across our projects we wrote a (*mini*) node.js module to initialize Redis connections: https://github.com/dwyl/redis-connection

[image: Build Status]
[image: Code Climate]
[image: codecov.io]
[image: Dependency Status]
[image: devDependency Status]

The code is simple and tested and takes care of ***authentication*** if required.
(*not copy-pasting the module here to avoid duplication*)
see: https://github.com/dwyl/redis-connection/blob/master/index.js

Usage:

### Install from NPM

`npm install redis-connection --save`

### Use in your script

```
var redisClient = require('redis-connection')();
redisClient.set('hello', 'world');
redisClient.get('hello', function (err, reply) {
  console.log('hello', reply.toString()); // hello world
});
```

### Publish Subscribe

```
var redisClient = require('redis-connection')(); // Publisher
var redisSub = require('redis-connection')('subscriber');
redisSub.subscribe("chat:messages:latest", "chat:people:new");
```

For a working example see: https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-socketio-redis-chat-example

The advantage is that we can re-use the same `redisClient` across multiple files in the same project without creating new connections (*the single or pub/sub connection is cached and re-used*)

**Credit**: We borrowed ideas from several places so have up-voted all the answers. But ultimately we wrote a slightly different solution so we have shared it with everyone on NPM/GitHub. Thanks again everyone!

Comment: is this maintained actively?

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran StackOverflow is probably not the best place to ask these kinds of questions, but yes, we are still using it in production for a few of our node.js apps. If you need any support or want to update anything, please open an issue on GitHub. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not tested, but too long for a comment.

Try to define another redis connection module, one for your regular usage and a second one solely for your pubsub subscriptions usage.

Add a `redis_pubsub_connection.js` to your project:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var url   = require('url');
var redisURL    = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL);
var redisPubSubClient = redis.createClient(redisURL.port, redisURL.hostname,
                  {no_ready_check: true});
redisPubSubClient.auth(redisURL.auth.split(":")[1]);

module.exports = redisPubSubClient;
```

And change your `publish.js` require statement to:

```
var redis = require('./redis_pubsub_connection'); // RedisCloud
```

Comment: This is a simple solution to the problem but would require 3 very similar modules: **redis_pub_connection.js** + **redis_sub_connection.js** + **redis_connection.js** because pub and sub cannot be the same and we still want to be able to GET/SET keys so we'd need the third one too.

Comment: @nelsonic, you should be good publishing messages on the regular connection. One separate connection for subscribers is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your redis client creation code is being cached by requires so you reuse the same connection again and again. Instead of returning the connection in your redis_connection module, you could return a function:

```
module.exports = function(){
    var redis = require('redis'); 
    var url = require('url'); var redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL); 
    var redisClient = redis.createClient(redisURL.port, redisURL.hostname, {no_ready_check: true});
    redisClient.auth(redisURL.auth.split(":")
    return redisClient;
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
var redisClient = require('./redis_connection.js')();
```

Comment: This solution will open and close connection per request.

Comment: @OfirLuzon we do *want* to open *multiple distinct* Redis connections but ***not*** for every request ... do you have an alternative suggestion?

Comment: My solution will open a distinct connection every time it's called. You can call it once in a module, when that module loads and then reuse that same connection throughout a modules lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to supply regular connection and a sub one and you want  to ensure you only have one of each across the application than you could use a combination of the two solutions that includes the notion of a singleton, something like this:

```
var subConnection, con;

var createConnection = module.exports.createConnection = function(){
    var redis = require('redis'); 
    var url = require('url'); var redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL); 
    var redisClient = redis.createClient(redisURL.port, redisURL.hostname, {no_ready_check: true});
    redisClient.auth(redisURL.auth.split(":")
    return redisClient;
}

module.exports.getSubConnection = function(){

if (!subConnection) 
    subConnection = createConnection();

return subConnection
}

module.exports.getConnection = function(){

if (!con) 
    con = createConnection();

return con
}

}
```

Repeat for the oher two connection types and call it like

```
var con =  require('./redis_connection.js').getConnection();
```

Comment: A dedicated connection for publish is not needed. Messages can be published on the regular connection.